# Using a classification Neural Net and parameter to ClassifierMeasurements[]

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I created and trained a simple neural net, which takes some inputs and produces a 3-class classification. Then I feed it to CM[] function with some test data, and... nothing. Haven't been successful with this no matter what I change about the net or the various function parameters. What am I missing?

[image: the errors I get]

Comment: Can you post the data somewhere?

Comment: You can generate sample data which will suit the network with a line like this:

data=(#/100-0.5)->If[Total@#>=7257&&Total@#<7736,0,If[Total@#<7257,-1,1]]&/@RandomInteger[100,{50000,150}];
It trains within 1500-2000 rounds to accuracy in excess of 99.5%

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For classification, you usually need a softmax layer in order for the default cross-entropy loss function to work.

So to solve your problem, you can just add a `SoftmaxLayer` to your network:

```
net = NetInitialize@
  NetChain[{3, LogisticSigmoid, 3, SoftmaxLayer[]}, "Input" -> {150}, 
   "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {-1, 0, 1}}]]

data = Table[RandomReal[1, {150}] -> RandomInteger[{-1, 1}], {5000}];

trained = 
 NetTrain[net, Take[data, 4500], 
  ValidationSet -> {Take[data, -500], "Interval" -> 5}]

cm = ClassifierMeasurements[trained, Take[data, -500]];

cm["Accuracy"]
(* 0.324 *)
```

Comment: Worked great! I was getting my results as 3-tuples of probabilities, then decoding them with the Class decoder, but a SoftmaxLayer[] produced a single class predictor and changed the loss function behind the scenes and that did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: what is "Interval" -> 5 in the option of `ValidationSet`  mean?

Comment: @partida It "specify the interval at which to calculate validation loss", i.e. calculate validation loss every 5 training round.